# H2 user-defined-function org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException non-hex character error

Tags: java, spring, h2, user-defined-functions, embedded-database

When attempting to pass a `List<String>` to an H2 user defined function, I'm getting the following error:

```
[{call MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(?)}]; SQL state 
[90004]; error code [90004]; Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: 
"[ABCD, EFGH]"; SQL statement:
call MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(?)  [90004-192]; nested 
exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-
hex character: "[1234, 5678]"; SQL statement:
call MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(?)  [90004-192]
```

As the snippet from the log shows, the list contains two strings: "ABCD" and "EFGH". I'm attempting to pass these values to a SQL statement's `IN` clause. 
The user-defined-function appears as follows:

```
CREATE ALIAS MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION AS
'
java.sql.ResultSet getTableContent(java.sql.Connection con, List<String> idList) throws Exception {
final PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id IN (?)");

String ids[] = new String[idList.size()];
idList.toArray(ids);
statement.setArray(1, con.createArrayOf("text", ids));

java.sql.ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
return rs;
}'
```

The user-defined-function is being called from a DAO method. I'm using Spring to manage the DB connections, here's a snippet of the calling method:

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjects(final List<String> idList) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("idList", idList);
    // Execute stored procedure
    Map<String, Object> output = super.execute(params);
    // Collect stored procedure results into list
    List<MyObject> myObjectList = (List<MyObject>) output.get("myResultSet");

    return myObjectList;
}
```

I've also tried passing an array, and using `setObject` on the prepared statement -- same error is thrown. I'm able to get the user-defined-function to return when passing in a single string, and calling `setString` on the prepared statement, but can't seem to pass multiple strings to the `IN` clause of the SQL statement.

Any ideas on why this is being thrown?

Comment: why `con.createArrayOf("text"...` Is your id of `TEXT` type? Usually it is  `BIGINT`, sometimes `VARCHAR`

Comment: @varren - in this case the column id is defined as a `VARCHAR`. I've tried using both `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` in the  `con.createArrayOf()` method -- same error is thrown each time. From what I can tell, something about the input param `List<String>` is causing the error to be thrown, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Had declared the input parameter type as `Types.VARCHAR`, changed to `Types.JAVA_OBJECT` and resolved the hex character issue:

```
StoredProcedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("idList", Types.JAVA_OBJECT));
```